# Prometheus error: couldn't load configuration. Found multiple scrape configs

Tags: prometheus, bosh

As the title says, I have ran into a prometheus exception and cannot figure out how to fix it.

We use a BOSH deployment like so:

```
bosh -d prometheus deploy -n prometheus.yml \
-o prometheus-boshrelease/manifests/operators/monitor-concourse.yml \
-o prometheus-boshrelease/manifests/operators/monitor-bosh.yml \
...
```

We then do a manifest update like so:

```
- type: replace
path: /instance_groups/name=prometheus2/jobs/name=prometheus2/properties/prometheus/scrape_configs/-
value:
  job_name: concourse
  scrape_interval: 2m
  scrape_timeout: 1m
  static_configs:
    - targets:
      - 192.168.123.123:9391
```

During the deploy we get an error that the prometheus2 instance is not running. Within the `prometheus.stderr.log` is where I found the error message:

> found multiple scrape configs with job name \"concourse\"

How can I get the bosh and concourse exporters to work together? Is it something to do with my manifest modification? Looking for any ideas, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already add this scrape config by applying the ops-file `monitor-bosh.yml`.
https://github.com/bosh-prometheus/prometheus-boshrelease/blob/master/manifests/operators/monitor-bosh.yml#L199-L219

This enables auto discovery of your concourse deployment (if concourse is also deployed by bosh).

If you do not want to use auto-discovery but staticly configure your concourse endpoint (what I do not recommend though), you have to remove the part I linked from your deployment first.
This could be done with an ops-file like this (not tested):

```
- type: remove
  path: /instance_groups/name=prometheus2/jobs/name=prometheus2/properties/prometheus/scrape_configs/job_name=concourse?
```

It has to be applied before you apply your changes.